# Whats the accurate meaning of this ごまかすin this sentence?

Tags: meaning, manga

> 照れ臭くなるとすぐごまかす... これじゃわかんなぃよ

She doesn't understand the person because when the person feels awkward she ...plays it off/trying to hide it?

Comment: See the second definition in [jisho](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%94%E3%81%BE%E3%81%8B%E3%81%99). Also the subject for わかんなぃ might be the speaker.

Comment: Oops that was the intention, I had it fixed.  But what would  you say is accurate, she tries to deceive her so she doesn't get her?

Comment: I have no idea what is the full context so here’s my guess: "When she gets embarrassed, she immediately dodges my questions... with this, there’s no way I can understand her"

Comment: Please [provide more context](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2189/5010). ごまかす is a transitive verb, and the correct translation depends on what the implied object is.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, she pretends that she has no idea.
So the speaker says "Don't cheat, or You cheat me!(ごまかしてる)"

Answer (score 0):

ごまかす has a few meanings whether with a malicious or innocent intent.  But it essentially means an act to hide the truth.  The one in the question is no exception.

Take the following examples.

数字をごまかす would mean to cheat the number like providing a false profit report when the company is losing money

話をごまかす would mean to intentionally not answer a question satisfactorily, to evade the question, or to answer it vaguely, all to let the true answer hidden.  Changing the subject is considered the same. **It's an act of trying to not talk about the subject**.

Below exchange illustrates how one might ごまかす in a casual conversation where A hints to like a girl, B pursues the topic, and A keeps evading.  Notice the use of 2 やさしい. 優しい（kind) gets switched to 易しい（easy) with an intention to go off topic.

- A: 彼女｛かのじょ｝って優｛やさ｝しいよね
- B: ひょっとして彼女の事｛こと｝好｛す｝き？
- A: やさしいといえば昨日｛きのう｝のテスト易｛やさ｝しかったね
- B: 話｛はなし｝をごまかさないで答えろ
- A: 答｛こた｝えは簡単｛かんたん｝。みんな９０%以上｛いじょう｝
- B: 彼女の話！
- A: 確率｛かくりつ｝５０%位｛くらい｝
- B: 自信｛じしん｝がないって事｛こと｝？
- A: 話をごまかすのが上手{じょうず｝でも、テストはごまかせないから。
- B: それは単｛たん｝に君｛きみ｝が５０%って事じゃないか

The sentence in the question follows a similar logic as to why わかんない or hard to understand the other person. Notice how A evades the questions by using related words but going off topic. But he isn't saying No either, just not answering purposefully. That's one way to 話をごまかす.

Below the translation of the above example.

- A: she is nice
- B: do you like her?
- A: speaking of which. Wasn't the test yesterday easy?
- B: Answer the question please.
- A: The answer is easy.  All should get 90% or more.
- B: I'm talking about her
- A: 50% chance
- B: Meaning you aren't very confident (that she'd go out with you)?
- A: Being good at fooling people doesn't necessarily mean it's possible to cheat a test
- B: That only means you get 50%